# Trouble swapping images using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have created my own javascript class as such:

```
function BeersOfTheWeek(){
    this.htmlImgObj = document.getElementById("beerImage");
    this.imgSources = ["guinness.jpeg","Heineken.png","SAM-ADAMS-BEER.jpg"];
    this.currentImgNmbr = 0;
    this.htmlImgObj.src = this.imgSources[this.currentImgNmbr];
    this.htmlImgObj.className = 'slideInRight';
}

BeersOfTheWeek.prototype.rotateNextBeer = function(){

    if(this.currentImgNmbr == (this.imgSources.length - 1)){
        this.currentImgNmbr = 0;
    } else {
        this.currentImgNmbr++;
    }
    this.htmlImgObj.src = this.imgSources[this.currentImgNmbr];
    this.htmlImgObj.className = 'slideInRight';
};
```

I'm trying to use the rotateNextBeer() function to continuously display another image every five seconds, and I am doing this by calling:

```
<script>
    window.setInterval("globals.botw.rotateNextBeer()",5000);
</script>
```

in my html file.

I have a .js file that contains some global variables for my project, and the relevant code for this object is this:

```
var globals = {};
globals.botw = new BeersOfTheWeek();
```

My issue is that my website will display the first image in imgSources no problem, but when window.setInterval() is triggered every five seconds, nothing happens.  It seems to get stuck and the first image displayed never changes.

Comment: The real question is why? Why create a class to do regular DOM manip stuff ?

Comment: Never pass strings to `setInterval`. Pass a function.

Comment: It's just a convenient way to keep track of my image sources and to make sure the images follow a set order for when they are displayed.

Comment: any decent js validator would have caught that typo.

Comment: @KevinB - assigment *can be done* in a condition, even if it's not very good practice, so it's not really an error.

Comment: Sure, it's valid, but any of the validators i've used in the past will give a warning on that line.

Comment: I've tried it both ways, and it did not effect anything

Comment: It seems to be working after the conditional update for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lhogezs/

Comment: That's interesting, it's still not working for me.  The conditional issue was a typo, I edited my original post.  I also tried changing the innerHTML rather than the src, but it had no effect unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single equals which is the assignment operator. 
You need to use a double equals instead (==), as you are trying to compare two values.
Or indeed, the identical to operator (===), if you want to compare the operands' values and types.

```
if(this.currentImgNmbr = (this.imgSources.length - 1)){
```

Should be:

```
if(this.currentImgNmbr == (this.imgSources.length - 1)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if(this.currentImgNmbr = (this.imgSources.length - 1)){
```

to be a proper comparison instead of an assignment.  `=` does assignment.  `==` does comparison:

```
if(this.currentImgNmbr == (this.imgSources.length - 1)){
```

---

FYI, a common design pattern for rotating through a fixed length without the `if/else` is to use the modulo operator like this:

```
BeersOfTheWeek.prototype.rotateNextBeer = function(){

    this.currentImgNmbr = (this.currentImgNmbr + 1) % this.imgSources.length
    this.htmlImgObj.src = this.imgSources[this.currentImgNmbr];
    this.htmlImgObj.className = 'slideInRight';
};
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part.  I have it correct in my source code.  I'll edit my post for that

Comment: Then, it's not clear what is wrong.  It looks to me like the images will change just fine, but I don't see you ever remove the `slideInRight` class so the images won't get a transition based on that if that's what you were trying to do.  Did you put a breakpoint or `console.log()` in the `rotateNextBeer()` function to see what it does the second time?  This is elementary debugging.

Comment: Indeed. A fiddle demonstrating your slider not working would be helpful.

Comment: I have been using the debugger, and the issue is that rotateNextBeer() isn't triggered again, even though it should be every 5 seconds